# Prove the converse of Ceva's theorem indirectly

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone push me in the right direction in the process of an indirect proof for the converse of ceva's theorem? Suggestions--though please be clear and all that--will suffice as an 'answer'.

Edit: Ceva's theorem is the theorem stating in a triangle ABC, if the lines AX, BY, and CZ (X being on BC, and so forth) are concurrent, then:

(BX/XC) * (CY/YA) * (AZ/ZB) = 1.

The converse would be that given ^^, prove the lines are concurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a "Ceva" triangle, i.e. let AX intersects CZ at some point P, extend BP to intersect AC at Y'. It follows from Ceva's theoreom that $$\frac{BX}{XC} \frac{CY'}{Y'A} \frac{AZ}{ZB} = 1$$.

[image]

Now, let $Y$ be a point on AC that is distinct from Y' (i.e. BY, CZ, AX are not concurrent), and that the ratio $\frac{BX}{XC} \frac{CY}{YA} \frac{AZ}{ZB} = 1$ holds.

Equating both ratios, we get
$$\frac{CY'}{Y'A} = \frac{CY}{YA}$$

But ratio of lengths on a line are invariant, thus $Y$, $Y'$ are the same point, contradicting our hypothesis. Therefore, BY, CZ, AX are concurrent.

Comment: Beautiful, but is this an indirect proof? (genuine question)

Comment: Basically we implicitly assumed that $Y \neq Y'$(I edited to make that obvious), and proved they are in fact the same by invariance of ratios. Please let me know if you have something different in mind? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind the question I just deleted about the invariant of ratios. I just got it. Thank you!